# How can I get rid of PDF Architect desktop ads?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, pdf-reader, advertisements

I have the PDF Architect 3 installed on my computer (Windows 7). This super-annoying pop-up ad appears in the right corner of the desktop each time I start my computer:

[image]

Can I disable it somehow? There is a [thread](http://forums.pdfforge.org/t/how-to-disable-desktop-ads-in-pdf-architect-3/8170/20) on this topic on pdfforge forum, but the issue doesn't seem to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities, depending on whether you have the free or paid
version of PDF Architect 3.

If you are using the **free version**, I don't see any reason not to upgrade
to the free version of PDF Architect 5.

If you are using the **paid version**, you shouldn't be getting this ad.
A similar problem was expressed in the thread
[How to disable desktop ads in PDF Architect 3](http://forums.pdfforge.org/t/how-to-disable-desktop-ads-in-pdf-architect-3/8170).
In response #13, a person named Robin.W said :

> if we can can't quickly find a solution to this, we will give you a
>   free update to PDF Architect 5. So far all tests indicate it only
>   happens when there are multiple versions installed.
>
> The notifications get displayed by a service called "PDF Architect
>   Manager", please run services.msc and disable any PDF Architect
>   Manager services. Since PDF Architect gets installed together with
>   PDFCreator by default, did you check there is really no other version
>   of it on the system, even if you didn't actively install one? Did your
>   license key get exchanged by our support at any point of time?

So your options in this case are two :

1. Disable the service named PDF Architect Manager.
2. If that does not work, contact the company and ask for a free upgrade
   to version 5, or at least a fixed version 3.